# 'Collections.unmodifiableCollection' in constructor

Tags: java, constructor, defensive-copy

From time to time during code reviews I see constructors like that one:

```
Foo(Collection<String> words) {
    this.words = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(words);
}
```

Is this proper way of protecting internal state of the class? If not, what's the idiomatic approach to create proper defensive copy in constructors?

Comment: Protecting self from self... 1) Constructors should only assign parameters to fields. 2) Making an argument unmodifiable in local scope does not mean it's unmodifiable at the call-site this constructor was invoked from. 3) If it must be unmodifiable, let the call-site wrap it. 4) If it's supposed to be exposed elsewhere, you might think of an unmodifiable _copy_ (usually created in a static factory method).

Answer (score 2):

It should be, but it isn't correct because the caller can still modify the underlying list.

Instead of wrapping the list, you should make a defensive copy, for example by using Guava's [`ImmutableList`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) instead.

```
Foo(Collection<String> words) {
    if (words == null) {
       throw new NullPointerException( "words cannot be null" );
    }
    this.words = ImmutableList.copyOf(words);
    if (this.words.isEmpty()) { //example extra precondition
       throw new IllegalArgumentException( "words can't be empty" );
    }
}
```

So the correct way of establishing the initial state for the class is:

1. Check the input parameter for `null`.
2. If the input type isn't guaranteed to be immutable (as is the case with `Collection`), make a defensive copy. In this case, because the element type is immutable (`String`), a shallow copy will do, but if it wasn't, you'd have to make a deeper copy.
3. Perform any further precondition checking on the copy. (Performing it on the original could leave you open to [TOCTTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) attacks.)

Comment: I have just `Collection`, not necessarily this is a `List`

Comment: @MichalKordas You can still treat it as a `Collection`, it should make no difference. If it does, it is wrong to accept any collection in the first place.

Comment: @MichalKordas: That doesn't change biziclop's point. `Collections.unmodifiableCollection` just wraps an existing collection... if the caller can modify that collection, you're still not really protecting the internal state of the class.

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.unmodifiableCollection(words);
```

only creates wrapper via which you can't modify `words`, but it doesn't mean that `words` can't be modified elsewhere. For example:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
words.add("foo");
Collection<String> fixed = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(words);

System.out.println(fixed);
words.add("bar");
System.out.println(fixed);
```

result:

```
[foo]
[foo, bar]
```

If you want to preserve current state of `words` in unmodifiable collection you will need to create your own copy of elements from passed collection and then wrap it with `Collections.unmodifiableCollection(wordsCopy);`

like if you only want to preserve order of words:

```
this.words = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(new ArrayList<>(words));
// separate list holding current words ---------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: can you suggest how idiomatic constructor for `Collection` should look like including copy creation?

Comment: Collection is abstract type so we can't simply create new one. You could try using reflection to locate copying constructor (if there is any) but this could overcomplicate things. I would probably simply use `new ArrayList<>(words)` but if it is good solution may depend on what you want to do with it later.

Answer (score 0):

No, that doesn't protect it fully.

The idiom I like to use to make sure that the contents is immutable:

```
public Breaker(Collection<String> words) {
    this.words = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(
        Arrays.asList(
            words.toArray(
                new String[words.size()]
            )
        )
    );
}
```

The downside here though, is that if you pass in a HashSet or TreeSet, it'll lose the speed lookup.  You could do something other than converting it to a fixed size List if you cared about Hash or Tree characteristics.

Comment: Another downside is that we are getting rid of proper generic type since `toArray` returns `Object[]`, not `T[]`.

Comment: `toArray(String.class)` will not compile. You may wanted to use `toArray(new String[words.size()])` (also no casting is needed here)

Comment: Sorry, doing this without pulling up my IDE ;-)

Comment: Also possible in Java 8 is `Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Arrays.asList(words.stream().toArray(String[]::new)));`

Comment: True, now that you corrected that mistake, why `Arrays.asList(code.code(code))` instead of `new ArrayList<>(words)` :)

Comment: `Arrays.asList` creates a wrapper around the fixed-sized input array. `new ArrayList<>(words)` will create a variable sized array, which may end up bigger than required.

Comment: But that array will be used only by `Collections.unmodifiableCollection` which doesn't allow us to modify it anyway, so there is no real gain here (or I am missing something).

Comment: It's a minimal gain, but the gain is that the new ArrayList<> constructor may allocate a larger array than it needs to.  Arrays.asList uses the exact size of the array.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you meant in previous comment (well it means it is getting late or it is time for a break).